# Directives do not work after adding dependencies to module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, pug

I am working on angular application that is served by node server, and I am trying to include dependency in core.js file. Everything is working well until I add dependency to module. As soon as I add dependency to module, directives stop working for some reason. To be more specific, dependency I am trying to add is [btford.socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) and is installed with bower.

I have tried adding it through brackets as show below, and with `app.requires` which can also be seen below in comment. Error shown in console is [[$injector:modulerr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=test&p1=%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dbtford.socket-io%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dbtford.socket-io%250AG%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A1%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A117%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A134%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Aeb%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A249%250Ayc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A463%250Ayc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A274%250AZd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A83%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A294%253A192%250Ax.Callbacks%252Fl%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A24877%250Ax.Callbacks%252Fc.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A25702%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A2898%250AS%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A551%250AEventListener.handleEvent*x.ready.promise%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A6178%250Ax.prototype.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A1667%250Ax.prototype.init%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A1241%250Ax%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A240%250Ax.support%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A28045%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A27252%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A1%250A%0AG%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:391%0An@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:331%0Ag@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:134%0An@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:331%0Ag@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488%0Aeb@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:41:249%0Ayc%2Fc@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:463%0Ayc@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:20:274%0AZd@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:83%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:294:192%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fl@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:24877%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fc.fireWith@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:25702%0A.ready@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:2898%0AS@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:551%0AEventListener.handleEvent*x.ready.promise@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:6178%0Ax.prototype.ready@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:1667%0Ax.prototype.init@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:1241%0Ax@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:240%0Ax.support%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:28045%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:27252%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:1%0A).

Here is my core.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['btford.socket-io']);
// app.requires.push('btford.socket-io');

app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = "This is test.";

    $scope.loadData = function() {
        $http.get('/data').success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.loadData();
});
```

Here is layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script(src='javascripts/core.js')
  body(ng-app="test")
    block content
```

Here is index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    div(ng-controller="testController")
        p {{test}} Result should be 15 and is: {{5 + 10}}
        br
        p {{data[0].name}}
```

Before adding dependencies directives show expected results:

```
This is test. Result should be 15 and is: 15
MyName
```

But after adding dependency, they are just displayed as plain text with error [[$injector:modulerr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=test&p1=%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dbtford.socket-io%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dbtford.socket-io%250AG%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A1%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A117%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A134%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Aeb%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A249%250Ayc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A463%250Ayc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A274%250AZd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A83%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A294%253A192%250Ax.Callbacks%252Fl%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A24877%250Ax.Callbacks%252Fc.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A25702%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A2898%250AS%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A551%250AEventListener.handleEvent*x.ready.promise%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A6178%250Ax.prototype.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A1667%250Ax.prototype.init%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A1241%250Ax%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A240%250Ax.support%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A28045%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A27252%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fjquery%252F2.0.3%252Fjquery.min.js%253A4%253A1%250A%0AG%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:391%0An@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:331%0Ag@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:134%0An@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:331%0Ag@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488%0Aeb@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:41:249%0Ayc%2Fc@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:463%0Ayc@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:20:274%0AZd@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:83%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:294:192%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fl@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:24877%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fc.fireWith@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:25702%0A.ready@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:2898%0AS@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:551%0AEventListener.handleEvent*x.ready.promise@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:6178%0Ax.prototype.ready@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:1667%0Ax.prototype.init@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:1241%0Ax@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:240%0Ax.support%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:28045%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:27252%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F2.0.3%2Fjquery.min.js:4:1%0A):

```
{{test}} Result should be 15 and is: {{5 + 10}}
{{data[0].name}}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening, and how can I make it work?

Comment: I don't see any script in your html loading the btford.socket-io module.

Comment: @Deblaton Jean-Philippe I have just updated the question.

Comment: @JB Nizet How should I add it? Why is adding it through module dependency not enough?

Comment: @Miljac you should check the web browser console to see what error you're getting (if any). Ctrl + alt j (windows) and Cmd + option + j on (mac) or sometimes F12 follow by the console tab. Add the error to the question if you have any in there.

Comment: Like any other script: by adding a <script> to your HTML page. Angular modules are not dynamically loaded. They are not equivalent to requirejs modules.

Comment: @JB Nizet adding script did the trick (only thing to note is that I had to add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));` to app.js to be able to use that route), can you write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments adding `<script>` tag to HTML solved it.

only thing to note is that I had to add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));` to app.js to be able to use wanted route